# Redux: store.replaceReducer don't replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default (initialState = {}) =>  {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      import('../reducers').then(module => {
        console.log(createStore(module.default).getState());

        store.replaceReducer(module.default);

        console.log(store.getState());
      });
    });
  }

  return store;
};
```

First `console.log` new store which should succeed, second `console.log` store after `replaceReducer`, but store didn't replace, What I do is not correct?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I might be missing something but in the second replace you don't dispatch any action just call replaceReducer, so the state does not get change.
You need to dispatch an action after the replaceReducer to update the state using the replaced reducer.

Comment: This is not right. [`replaceReducer` will dispatch an action](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L216) similar to the `INIT` action (I think it was the `INIT` action before the v4 beta) and pass in the current state.  This allows the new reducer to discard old or add new parts of the state to match the new reducer